# Why does Java browser plugin detect Firefox as Chrome preventing verification of it's installation?

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, java-8

Here is what I have:

Windows 10 Premium 64bit
Firefox 50.0.1
Java 1.8.0-u111/112

Now here is the problem:

[image]

I am using Firefox 50.0.1 it says I am using Chrome,
so I cannot verify my Java installation and I'm all out of ideas.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: don't use java-plugin and java-applets. They are outdated and have security issues

Comment: if you just want to verify your java installation, simply open "cmd" and type "java -version".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

From the official Mozilla blog they wrote a post about this [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/):

> Mozilla intends to remove support for most NPAPI plugins in Firefox by the end of 2016.

So it seems that as we are approaching the "end of 2016", they have removed support for NPAPI and as JohnnyAW already commented, applets are outdated and are already starting to be deprecated for the most part. Browsers are moving towards HTML5 and other technologies to completely replace the use of Java Applets, Flash and other plugins as such.

From bugzilla, there has been an update to this issue 2 days ago, outlined [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1269807).

There is also [this resource](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/plug-in-support-has-been-dropped-other-than-flash/) explaining that all plugin support other than flash has been dropped.